# Login with facial recognition in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: login, authentication, pam

I have tried to install „PAM face authentication“ with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:antonio.chiurazzi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pam-face-authentication
```

But it seems, the latest package there, is for 11.04 „Natty Narwhal“. Is it possible to install and use it with Ubuntu 13.04 „Saucy Salamander“, or are there alternatives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any facial recognition software for logging in on Ubuntu 14.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/516710/is-there-any-facial-recognition-software-for-logging-in-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort of get [Biologin](http://pralab.diee.unica.it/en/Biologin) to work in Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit, but the display manager I'm using is gdm 3.8.4-0ubuntu2 .

It didn't let me see my face but my camera still turned on so I don't know if it's for lightdm.