# Is there any facial recognition software for logging in on Ubuntu 14.04/10

Tags: software-recommendation, login, auto-login

Is there any facial recognition software for logging in on Ubuntu 14.04? I've searched the web, and found projects like PAM and IMRSV Cara. I also found instructions for running these programs on older Ubuntu versions, but I couldn't find anything for Ubuntu 14.04/10.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this new ppa put together with the github version of pam-face-authentication which should be up to date with newer dependencies:

https://launchpad.net/~doctormo/+archive/ubuntu/opencv

Comment here if the package works for you or if it fails. I'll update this post with more install details if more people confirm.

Comment: It doesn't work with 16.04:
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pam-face-authentication:
 pam-face-authentication depends on libopencv-core2.4; however:
  Package libopencv-core2.4 is not installed.
 pam-face-authentication depends on libopencv-highgui2.4; however:
  Package libopencv-highgui2.4 is not installed.
 pam-face-authentication depends on libopencv-imgproc2.4; however:
  Package libopencv-imgproc2.4 is not installed.
 pam-face-authentication depends on libopencv-objdetect2.4; however:
  Package libopencv-objdetect2.4 is not installed.

Comment: The package is for Trusty, not xenial. It'll have to be re-compiled. I've sent a Xenial package up for recompilation, but I really have no idea if it will work until tested.